# Do browsers create caches of local HTML assets, such as SVGs or scripts?

Tags: browser, google-chrome, html

This question was asked over 7 years ago, but there wasn't a definitive answer.

In the following example, does the browser know not to create a cache for these local assets?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<img src="image.png">
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Does the browser (Chrome in this case) create a copy in the cache on load? I've looked at the network log which suggests to my inexperienced eyes that it doesn't attempt to pull from any caches, and just re-requests every time. However, I'd be very surprised if the browser caches *nothing* about a local HTML file.

Comment: Unless you provide more data, this isn't strictly security related.  See also [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12452993/812837) (although there might possibly be more up-to-date ways to do this now).

Comment: Where was is asked? Don't duplicate questions that do not have enough answers, instead, try to bring attention to it.